# Who did Mussolini meet after Hitler, on arrival to Germany after rescue?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, hitler, fascism, mussolini

Mussolini was flown to Germany after the [Gran Sasso raid.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gran_Sasso_raid)

Who does Mussolini meet, after Hitler, in [this video](https://youtu.be/zAWEoe1SwLs?t=24)? What does the narrator say (in German)? What does it mean?

[image: Two men greeting each other with an embrace.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mussolini met his own son.

The video description given seems indeed misleading.

[The description for the Youtube video "Mussolini arrives in Germany after being liberated and being greeted by Hitler and other Nazi leaders." says:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAWEoe1SwLs&t=24)

> Former Italian Prime Minister Benito Mussolini arrives in Germany after his liberation on October 10, 1943 during World War II. A Nazi aircraft arrives and Mussolini gets off it. German Chancellor Adolf Hitler greets Mussolini. An Italian Minister kisses Mussolini and German Foreign Minister Joachim von Ribbentrop greets Mussolini. He enters a building. Mussolini with German President of Reichstag Herman Goring and German Chancellor Adolf Hitler. They move out of the building and Mussolini gets into a car. At an airfield Mussolini boards an aircraft and Hitler waves. Location: Germany. Date: 1944.

The [website originating this video seems to claim the man to be Count Ciano.](https://www.criticalpast.com/video/65675059087_Benito-Mussolini_Adolf-Hitler_Herman-G%C3%B6ring_Joachim-von-Ribbentrop_Die-Wolfsschanze_Junkers-Ju-52-Flugzeuge) You know: ([Ciano!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galeazzo_Ciano) See below.)

> [image]

But the narrator clearly says (in German):

> The Duce greets his son Vittorio…

Which would be [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vittorio_Mussolini) to the right:

> [image]

A transcript shows that this was the climax news at the end of that propaganda reel:

> 10. Besuch des befreiten Mussolinis bei Hitler im Führerhauptquartier, Rastenburg, Ostpreußen, Deutsches Reich, 1943
>
> Ein Transportflugzeug vom Typ Ju 52 am Himmel. Landung auf einem Flugplatz des Führerhauptquartiers Wolfsschanze. Der gerade von einer deutschen Spezialeinheit befreite italienische Diktator Benito Mussolini tritt aus der Maschine und wird von Adolf Hitler begrüßt. **Mussolini begrüßt seinen Sohn Vittorio.** Abfahrt mit einem Wagen. Begrüßung Mussolinis durch Reichsaußenminister Joachim von Ribbentrop. Mussolini im Gespräch mit Reichsmarschall Hermann Göring, Oberbefehlshaber der Luftwaffe. Hitler und Mussolini treten aus dem Gebäude. Abfahrt zum Flughafen. Hitler und Ribbentrop verabschieden Mussolini. Die Maschine rollt an. Hitler grüßt zum Abschied.
> — [Die Deutsche Wochenschau (681 / 40 / 1943)](http://www.filmarchives-online.eu/viewDetailForm?FilmworkID=f6c22bf4220e20141a0b9fec9be7baa8)

[Alternative description in English](https://www.net-film.eu/film-53791/), and [reel on archive.org.](https://archive.org/details/1943-09-22-Die-Deutsche-Wochenschau-681)

If you are into profile comparisons or ear identification, in 1959, after this video opportunity, Vittorio visited his father's grave:

> [image]
>
> — [Il Duce Grave](https://www.gettyimages.dk/detail/news-photo/vittorio-mussolini-son-of-italian-dictator-benito-mussolini-news-photo/3246496)
>
> 16th March 1959: Vittorio Mussolini, son of Italian dictator Benito Mussolini, visiting his father's tomb at the cemetery in San Cassino, Province of Forli. (Photo by Keystone/Getty Images)

Note that the shown-in-video Vittorio is Mussolini's son, while wrongly identified Count Ciano was Mussolini's son-in-law — with Ciano even being in a large part responsible for creating the need to free Benito Mussolini in the first place: since it was Ciano who as a member of the Grand Fascist Council voted in favour of the decision to move Mussolini out of power in 1943, leading to Mussolini's arrest. Having *him* greet the freed Mussolini would have been … an interesting sight?